# Single query to return counts over different IDs in a single record

Tags: sql-server, query, select

```
select count(title_id)as algodata from titles where pub_id =1389  
select count(title_id)as binnet   from titles where pub_id =0877  
select count(title_id)as newmoon  from titles where pub_id =0736
```

The database used is `pubs` in SQL Server.

Can I use a single query to  show the count of records for each publisher (here there are 3 publishers) in a single record?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar to @ypercubes but to get one row without 3 separate queries

```
select
     count(CASE WHEN pub_id = '1389' THEN title_id END) as algodata,
     count(CASE WHEN pub_id = '0877' THEN title_id END) as binnet,   
     count(CASE WHEN pub_id = '0736' THEN title_id END) as newmoon  
from titles
where pub_id IN ('1389', '0877', '0736')
```

Also, decide if your values are numbers or strings and be consistent to avoid datatype conversions

Comment: You need to give the columns different aliases though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: oops. copy/paste error. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [`Pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) assuming you are on at least SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT [1389] AS algodata,
       [0877] AS binnet,
       [0736] AS newmoon
FROM   titles PIVOT (COUNT(title_id) FOR pub_id IN ([1389], [0877], [0736])) P
```

Answer (score 6):

Result in 3 rows:

```
SELECT pub_id 
     , COUNT(title_id) AS algodata 
FROM titles 
WHERE pub_id IN (1389, 877, 736)  
GROUP BY pub_id ;
```

To get the results in one row:

```
SELECT 
  ( select count(title_id) as algodata from titles where pub_id = 1389 ) AS algodata,
  ( select count(title_id) as binnet   from titles where pub_id = 0877 ) AS binnet,
  ( select count(title_id) as newmoon  from titles where pub_id = 0736 ) AS newmoon;
```

Comment: the first one is not the query i want but thanks for your info the second one is correct. ypercube thanks any way and for your fast reply

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You will need to use sub-queries to accomplish this though. The following link should guide you in the right direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189623(SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I will assert that you have a table

```
publishers(pub_id, pub_name)
```

with the primary key pub_id and the unique key oub_name
containing the rows

```
1389,'algodata'
0877,'binnet'
0736,'newmoon'
```

then the query

```
select p.pub_name,count(t.title_id)
from titles t, publishers p
where t.pub_id=p.pub_id
and p.pub_name in ('algodata','binnet','newmoon')
group by p.pub_name
/
```

will return  something like

```
135 binnet
 21 newmoon
 24 algodata
```

this is a little bit  different from your queries because in your queries the name of the publisher is the name of the column and not the value of a column